# convert number to decimal in php

Tags: php, numbers, format

I have a number stored in a variable. The number is pulled from the database as 9900..I need to convert this number to 99.00 in order to display to a customer in HTML.

I was wondering how can I achieve this in php.

Thanks.

Comment: What logic does the conversion follow? Divide by 100?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$priceInCents = 9900;
$priceInDollars = $priceInCents / 100;
```

And then you can use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) or [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) as you please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [number_format()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function for that:

```
echo number_format(9900/100);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by either using [money_format](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) or [number_format](http://dk.php.net/number_format), if you are going to display it as a price you should look at [money_format](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), otherwise,  [number_format](http://dk.php.net/number_format) is the way to go.

Comment: I didn't knew about the money function. Very handy, even tough the euro format is not correct.